# d3.js v5.9.1 - some methods in this version are not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, d3.js

I am using d3.js in an Angular 7.1.4 project. The version of d3 I am using is 5.9.1, which is the [latest version](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases) so far.

I installed this using npm [as follows](https://github.com/d3/d3):

`npm install d3`

which put `"d3": "^5.9.1"` in my `package.json` file.

I also installed `@types/d3` through npm with the command `npm install @types/d3`, and that put `"@types/d3": "^5.7.1"` in my `package.json` file.

With the `@types/d3` dependency, I imported d3 into my typescript files like so:

`import * as d3 from "d3";`, just like the [d3 github guide says](https://github.com/d3/d3).

Now, I am following an example on [this website](https://blog.risingstack.com/d3-js-tutorial-bar-charts-with-javascript/) that creates a bar graph using d3.

The full source code of the example is found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/matehu/w7h81xz2/) on jsfiddle, and if you look at their declared `<script>` tag, you will see that they are using d3 version 5.9.1, which is the same version I am using:

`<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>`

`// https://d3js.org v5.9.1 Copyright 2019 Mike Bostock`

However, when I copy the following code into my typescript file:

```
  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, 100]);

  const makeYLines = () => d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
```

I am getting an error at the `d3.axisLeft()` method call, and the error says:

`Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.`

However, the example on jsfiddle uses the same exact version that I have (5.9.1) and is not running into any problems.

Can someone explain what the problem is?

**EDIT:**

I just checked the minified js file and the original js file for `https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js` and the `axisLeft` method actually does take an argument:

`function axisLeft(scale) {
  return axis(left, scale);
}`

So how is the jsfiddle example calling the method without passing an argument to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you look at the `d3` source code a little further, the argument it's looking for you to pass is the `scale`:

```
function axis(orient, scale) {
  var tickArguments = [],
  ...
```

If you don't pass it the scale will go in as *undefined*.

**But** `axis` is a closure that provide an alternate way to provide a `scale` with a `.scale` "method".

```
axis.scale = function(_) {
  return arguments.length ? (scale = _, axis) : scale;
};
```

Your very next bit of code is passing the scale in using that "method".

Now with TypeScript certain concessions need to be made as it's not a loosy-goosy as JavaScript.  So the typings author chose to follow the axis function signature.  All that said, your TypeScript should just follow that example, and be:

```
const makeYLines = () => d3.axisLeft(yScale);
```